# Merge two tables and keep only duplicated values in R

Tags: r

I want to merge two tables and only keep similar `Task` from two tables. Non-common `Task` is removed. If two `Task`is similar, I only keep smaller value, 
Two tables like this

```
x<-data.frame("Task"=c("A","B","C","D","E"),"FC"=c(12,NA,15,14,NA),FH=c(13,15,NA,17,20))
   Task FC FH
1    A 12 13
2    B NA 15
3    C 15 NA
4    D 14 17
5    E NA 20
y<-data.frame("Task"=c("B","C","F","G"),"FC"=c(NA,12,20,NA),FH=c(NA,17,18,NA))
  Task FC FH
1    B NA NA
2    C 12 17
3    F 20 18
4    G NA NA
```

I want an output like this

```
  Task FC FH
2    B NA 15
3    C 12 17
```

Comment: Can you please explain the idea of the algorithm to take one record from `x` and the other from `y`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
x %>%
 bind_rows(y) %>%
 group_by(Task) %>%
 filter(n() > 1) %>%
 summarise_all(~ ifelse(all(is.na(.)), NA, min(., na.rm = TRUE)))

  Task     FC    FH
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 B        NA    15
2 C        12    17
```

Or if there could be duplicate tasks per single df:

```
x %>%
 bind_rows(y, .id = "ID") %>%
 group_by(Task) %>%
 filter(n() > 1 & n_distinct(ID) > 1) %>%
 summarise_all(~ ifelse(all(is.na(.)), NA, min(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
 select(-ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
# Perform a join
merged <- merge(x = x, y = y, by = "Task")

# Get the minimum value out of two comparable columns
merged$FC <- with(merged, pmin(FC.x, FC.y, na.rm = TRUE))
merged$FH <- with(merged, pmin(FH.x, FH.y, na.rm = TRUE))

# Delete the unwanted columns appearing out of merge
merged <- merged[-c(2:5)]
```

Output:

```
  Task FC FH
1    B NA 15
2    C 12 17
```